# To locate a 3d point from an existing 3d point using a vector and distance

Tags: python

I have a 3D point `A=(x,y,z)` a vector `Vec=(vx,vy,vz)` and a distance `d=10`, 
I need to create a point `B` from `A` in the direction of vector `Vec` at a distance `d` using python.

Comment: I need to find the coordinates of point B

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your code, including what you have now, and anything you've tried yourself to get this working.

Comment: `A + (d * (Vec / |Vec|))`  is what you're looking for in mathematical terms. This should help you write the code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some linear algebra will do the trick with numpy.

```
import numpy as np
point = np.array([1.,2,3])
vec = np.array([2.,0,0]) #Don't need unit vectors
disp = 10

def point_displacement(point, vec, disp):
    unit_vec = vec / np.linalg.norm(vec)
    return point + disp * unit_vec

point_displacement(point, vec, disp)
#array([11.,  2.,  3.])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can represent a vector in Python as a NumPy array in Python as follows.

```
vec = array([vx, vy, vz])
```

In your case the point `A=(x,y,z)` and the vector `Vec=(vx,vy,vz)` will both be treated the same mathematically if x,y,z,vx,vy, and vz are all treated as scalars. 
With a geometric analogy we can say that a vector represents a point or coordinate in an n-dimensional space. So, we can define A as follows.

```
A = array([x,y,z])
```

You can find the unit vector corresponding to the the vector vec as follows in Python.

```
uv = vec / np.linalg.norm(vec)
```

Finally you can get the desired point as follows,

```
point = A + disp * uv
```

You also need to import NumPy at the beginning as follows.

```
import numpy as np
```